# Numpy. Преобразования Фурье. Порядок гармоник

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, fft

Есть ли строгое правило порядка гармоник при использовании np.fft.ifft?
Должна ли 0-я гармоника сигнала обязательно являться первым элементом входного массива?
Допустим у меня имеется 5 гармоник сигнала: -2 -1 0 1 2. Какой должен быть порядок передачи их в функцию np.fft.ifft для получения корректного результата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Должна ли 0-я гармоника сигнала обязательно являться первым элементом входного массива?

Да, это явно сказано в [описании](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html) ifft

По обычно используемому соглашению после прямого Фурье положительные частоты занимают ячейки от 0 до n/2, потом идут перенесённые отрицательные частоты (если сигнал был чисто реальный, это точное зеркальное отражение первой половины массива).

Если ваше описание `-2 -1 0 1 2` подразумевает отрицательные частоты, то их нужно упаковать так:

```
 0  1  2  -2  -1
```